# Clicking on a hypertext link using XPath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, click

Apologies if this is a dumb question - I'm new to Selenium.

I have a web page I'm testing that has a few hypertext links in a table. The HTML looks like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><b>History</b></td>
      <td><b>Attributes</b></td>
      <td><b>Xml</b></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>    
    <tr>
      <td><a href=link here>Show</a></td> 
      <td><a href=link here>Show</a></td>
      <td><a href=link here>Show</a></td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to test a click on each of the 'Show' links. They all have the same text, so I can't reference them by linktext. I've been referencing them by XPath, so that:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div/form/div/table[2]/thead/tr/td[1]").getText()
```

correctly returns 'History' and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div/form/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]").getText()
```

correct returns 'Show'.

So I would think that:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div/form/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click()
```

would click on the 'Show' link in the first column. But it doesn't - nothing happens.

If I do:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Show")).click()
```

it clicks on the first 'Show' link, which is what I expect.

I can also do:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div/form/div/table[2].1.0")).click()
```

and that works, as does

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Show')])[2]")).click()
```

So, to sum, all of these work:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Show")).click()
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div/form/div/table[2].1.0")).click()
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Show')])[1]")).click()
```

but this doesn't:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div/form/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click()
```

Why?

Comment: I think you should follow one element deeper, to the `a` within `td`. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div/form/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a")).click() `. You should be clicking the link, not the cell that contains it.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You can gather all the links together by using `findElements` and then iterate through the array.

Example - 
`List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input"));`

and in your case

`List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Show"));`

and then iterate through `links` and click on each one of them

Comment: That wouldn't have helped as I wouldn't know which 'Show' link I was clicking on - they could (conceivably) be in any order.

Comment: No, it will be in the same order as that displayed in the source HTML. I would recommend trying it out, before disregarding it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't inspect the HTML at run time to know which order they are in.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the expression in question

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div/form/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click()
```

selects a `td` element, in case of which no link or event is defined. While clicking it in browser should open a link, it will happen only because you're effectively clicking what's inside the tag as well as the `td` itself. The code above only clicks the `td`, ignoring its content.

You have to go one step deeper, to the `a` element within your currently selected `td`. Like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content']/div/form/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a")).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

### List links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

then iterate through links and click on each one of them using for loop